# How can I see the parameters in intellisense in a spark file?

Tags: spark-view-engine

I've got spark intellisense working but when I open the parameters `()` of the method I can not see what is supposed to go in there and several of the methods have overloads so I can't see what options I have.

For example `!{Html.Hidden()}` once I open the `()` I can not see what parameters I am to pass

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem

Resharper interferring with the intellisense.

solution is here http://sparkviewengine.com/usage/intellisense